# iOS app, place to save user id and password

Tags: iphone

I am new to IOS development. Anyone can advise where is the best place to save the user id and password? My app is running on iPhone.

Thanks
Aimar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try save confidential information, such as userId and token in Keychain. This one is simple and straightforward https://github.com/kharrison/UYLPasswordManager.

Regards
Hammer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Keychain` to store the users username and password securely. Apple do actually provide some example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/generickeychain/listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html). You want to be looking at the KeychainItemWrapper classes. And if you want something a little more advanced you could also have a look at implementing the KeychainTouchID example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html).

If you don't want to use Apples version though there are a selection of alternatives online

- [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain)
- [FXKeychain](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain)
- [LUKeychainAccess](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/LUKeychainAccess)
- [And here's the google search I did](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=3rd%20party%20keychain%20objective-c&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=26VQVL_eOpP5iQb6toCgBQ#safe=active&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=%20keychain%20objective-c%20github)